# All Nippon Airlines sent my baggage to the transit instead of the destination airport, both within the EU. Is this normal?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, luggage, eu

2-leg flight booked with All Nippon Airlines. The first one operated by them, the second one operated by Lufthansa. Both the transit (Germany) and destination airports within the EU.

ANA checked my baggage to the transit airport instead of the destination airport even though they are both located in the EU.

I lost the connecting flight due to having to pick up and check the luggage back in.

Is there a reason for this or is it the airlines' mistake? I thought that customs had to cleared in the destination airport for EU-bound flights.

Comment: Did LH put you on the next flight ? That's certainly unusual and your assumption is generally correct. However, there can always be exceptions.

Comment: What was the destination airport? I believe the usual check-through is possible only if the final airport has customs facilities, which is very often, but not always, the case. But they should have factored that in in the MCT and they should have rebooked you on the next flight.

Comment: The booked me on the next flight, 7 hours later, which was actually a 2-leg flight because the original one was the last of the day. Less than ideal.

Asking in the LH service center they were surprised about my bags being sent to the transit airport, LH and ANA being partners.

Comment: It might have been a mistake, or some kind of policy, but without knowing the airports it's hard to be sure.